# IB outlets are getting nil even though they are connected in storyboard

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, null

I am new to Xcode and I have created an UIPageViewController and a view controller as it's data container here's my code:

```
class RootPageControllerViewController: UIPageViewController,UIPageViewControllerDataSource {
    
    var myControllers:[UIViewController] = []
    let pages:[String] = ["first","second","third","fourth","fifth","six","seven"]
    let story = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        for text in pages{
            let vc = self.story.instantiateViewController(identifier: "dataContainer") as! DataContainer
            vc.setText(text)
            myControllers.append(vc)
        }
        configureController()
    }
    
    func configureController(){
        self.dataSource = self
        if let first = myControllers.first{
            self.setViewControllers([first], direction: .forward, animated: true,completion: nil)
        }
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerBefore viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard let index = myControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController),index>0 else { return nil }
        let before = index-1
        return myControllers[before]
    }
    
    func pageViewController(_ pageViewController: UIPageViewController, viewControllerAfter viewController: UIViewController) -> UIViewController? {
        guard  let index = myControllers.firstIndex(of: viewController),index<(myControllers.count - 1) else {
            return nil
        }
        let after = index + 1
        return myControllers[after]
    }
    
}

class DataContainer: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var titleView: UILabel!
    
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    
    func setText(_ mssg:String){
        if titleView != nil{
            titleView.text = mssg
        }
        else{
            print("reference is null")
        }
    }
}
```

my outlet's are connected properly and I have checked them many times but then also they are becoming nil at run time...how can I prevent the dereferencing of outlets

Comment: plz provide the error log as well

Answer (score 0):

`@IBOutlet` connections are not valid until the view has been loaded.

When you `.instantiateViewController`, you get a reference to that controller object, but the view has not yet been loaded.

Here is one way to fix that:

```
    for text in pages{
        let vc = self.story.instantiateViewController(identifier: "dataContainer") as! DataContainer
        
        // add this line
        vc.loadViewIfNeeded()
        
        vc.setText(text)
        myControllers.append(vc)
    }
```